# How can I call a Python Script (with params) running on AWS EC2 from Salesforce?

Tags: python, aws

I have built a Python script on an Ubuntu EC2 instance (AWS).  How can I use a callout (or URL) on Salesforce.com to kickoff that script in the easiest way possible - what I mean is, I do not want to write an API, etc.  I simply need a simple way to kick it off.  Using other parts of the AWS platform/services is possible if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need a way to get a signal to the ec2 instance to run the python script, and the only connection method that an ec2 instance provides itself when you start it up (that I know of) is through ssh - which Salesforce doesn't have.

Pretty much your only option for communicating from Salesforce to other systems is the Http request (although email services are possible). So even if you don't want to build a full api for your python service, you are still probably going to have to add something to your ec2 instance to accept (and validate) http requests from Salesforce.

Comment: Just beat me to it. We use SQS to send messages from Salesforce to an EB server that listens for messages from the queue and then processes data. It's really not too hard, but does require the intermediate step.